# IEnumerable Collection declaration & population

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create an IEnumerable collection of type `IEnumerable<string,int,int>`

How can I create it & populate it with data?

Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Tuple<string,int,int>` as the generic type of `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var myData = new List<Tuple<string,int,int>>();

myData.Add(new Tuple<string,int,int>("myString", 1, 2));
```

However, if this data has meaning beyond a single method, I suggest creating a class with your  fields to be used as the generic type of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: How to populate it with data then?

Comment: Thanks for solution, but if a class to be created then how i to create it & populate it

Comment: Classes can be created quite simply, and is the basis of OO programming. If you are struggling to do that I suggest you look for an online resource on the basics of OO programming.
Once you've created your class - adding it would be relatively simply myData.Add(new myClass (etc.......)

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking you can't *create* an IEnumerable collection of anything - because IEnumerable is an interface, and you can't create instances of interfaces. You have to create an instance of some class that implements IEnumerable<sup>1</sup>.

So you want something like a `List<string, int, int>`, but as Oded implies, that's not possible, as `List<T>` can only contain **one** generic parameter (this is also the case for IEnumerable).

Thus, what Oded is proposing is for you to use a 'wrapper' class to enclose your three values into just one value which can be used as the `T` in your List.

If, as your last comment suggests, you don't know how to create and populate a class, or a list, I think you need to do a bit more research...

<sup>1</sup>*I guess Enumerable.Range might count as a pseudo-exception here...*